# How do I filter out No Data Available cell in Cognos?

Tags: excel, cognos

I am using Cognos 11 and have created a report. My report has a number of lists embedded within it. I have filtered some of the data items e.g. excluded no etc. When I run my report I get No data available in some of the cells. This data is to be excluded.

However, when I run the report and convert it into Excel, I get No Data Available for these excluded data points. How can I exclude/supress for No Data Available? I have tried many different options in conditional styling, data items and Supress but do not seem to be selecting the correct option?

Answer (score 2):

"No data available" is the default presentation when a list or crosstab produces no results.  It is not a per cell setting.

You can change this by setting the *No data contents* property of the list or crosstab.

This information can be found by searching the [Cognos documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.doc/t_no_data_in_data_container.html#no_data_in_data_container) for "No Data Available".

Answer (score 0):

A list within a list will either use a section or a master-detail relationship.  The no data available cells are caused by a match in the data for the section and or master-detail relationship but no detail values.  So if you have a report which has product line and revenue where 1 product line has no revenue values,  it will display the no data available for that particular product line.  You might be able to add a detail filter which filters out the Revenue<>Null or Revenue <>0.